# Prestashop Webservice Update Customer via PUT Disables Customer Login

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I have the following PERL code that works when creating a new customer via Prestashop 1.6 webservice:

```
my $endPoint = 'https://storeURL.com/api/customers?ws_key=MY_KEY';
my $req_XML = qq{
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <customer>
        <id>$frm{id}</id>
        <passwd required="true" maxSize="32" format="isPasswd">$rndPass</passwd>
        <lastname required="true" maxSize="32" format="isName">$frm{lastname}</lastname>
        <firstname required="true" maxSize="32" format="isName">$frm{firstname}</firstname>
        <email required="true" maxSize="128" format="isEmail">$frm{email}</email>
        <active format="isBool">1</active>
        <id_default_group>$frm{group}</id_default_group>
        <associations>
            <groups nodeType="group" api="groups">
                <group>
                    <id>$frm{group}</id>
                </group>
            </groups>
        </associations>
    </customer>
</prestashop>
};
$xml_resp = $ua->request(POST $endPoint, Content_Type => 'text/xml', Content => $req_XML);
```

OK, so again, that works. When creating a customer there is no `id` in the form  input - so it is a blank entry. When I use the exact same XML to edit a customer with a PUT request:

```
$xml_resp = $ua->request(PUT $endPoint, Content_Type => 'text/xml', Content => $req_XML);
```

the update seems to work, meaning: when you check the Prestashop back end, the customer is there, the changes (like a change to a name or email) are visible and it indicates the customer is active and everything looks good. However, that particular customer can no longer login to the shop.

I get:`Authentication Error` and a red banner on the login screen.

So, I don't know where I am going wrong with the PUT request.

I have tried to issue a new password, tried to leave the passwd field blank, tried to remove the passwd field (error: `[parameter "passwd" required]`), tried to grab the hashed password out the `ps_customer` table in the DB and pass that, tried to give every customer the same password when registering and updateing, tried some stuff I can't remember ...

The result has been the same: unless an error was triggered, the update looks like it took place but the customer cannot login.

I am figuring that I am missing something - either the PUT request is insufficient in some way or not the method I should be using. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i would check the customer data just to be sure, and what about the address information?

Secondly prestashop is updating his password encryption. Try updating your store and then use the "forgot password" on each account to set a new password.

This change was between 1.5 - 1.7

from `blowfish` to using a more secure `symfony::crypto` function.

To check the password through the webservice you could use `password_verify` in `php`. See the example below.

```
$salt = substr($info->passwd, strrpos($info->passwd, ':') + 1, 2);
        $ZCpassword = md5($COOKIE_KEY . $password) . ':' . $salt;

        if (password_verify($password, $info->passwd) == true) {
            session_start();
            $response = array();
            $response['status'] = 'succes';
            $response['message'] = "http://sdwebdesign.nl/wessel/easycheckout/#/productpage";
            setcookie("userId", $info->id);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response = array();
            $response['status'] = 'error';
            $response['message'] = 'Uw wachtwoord is verkeerd';
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Comment: I moved on from this a long time ago and just saw your answer.  Don't know if this answers my question or not. If someone can comment that it is a good answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @cbmckay i've been using this code for a while so yes it is working (;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it sending the fields <id_shop> and <id_shop_group> :)